# Make a button show as a link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have this button that calls a javascript function,.. how can i make it into a link?

```
<button onclick="openWin(); return false;">
            Choose Destination and date</button>
```

Comment: Presumably you've of course attempted to use the HTML element that is desgned for this, the `a` tag.  What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @KirkWoll This can be a relevant question when you'd like to perform a form action, such as a delete, but have it styled as a link.  You would use a button in this case to keep search engines from "clicking" it.

Comment: @Chris, if you're using a "button" then it's not a link, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="link/to/page/in/case/javascript/is/off" onclick="openWin(); return false;">
    Choose Destination and date
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<asp:HyperLink />` control.

Here is some documentation

```
<asp:HyperLink
    AccessKey="string"
    BackColor="color name|#dddddd"
    BorderColor="color name|#dddddd"
    BorderStyle="NotSet|None|Dotted|Dashed|Solid|Double|Groove|Ridge|
        Inset|Outset"
    BorderWidth="size"
    CssClass="string"
    Enabled="True|False"
    EnableTheming="True|False"
    EnableViewState="True|False"
    Font-Bold="True|False"
    Font-Italic="True|False"
    Font-Names="string"
    Font-Overline="True|False"
    Font-Size="string|Smaller|Larger|XX-Small|X-Small|Small|Medium|
        Large|X-Large|XX-Large"
    Font-Strikeout="True|False"
    Font-Underline="True|False"
    ForeColor="color name|#dddddd"
    Height="size"
    ID="string"
    ImageUrl="uri"
    NavigateUrl="uri"
    OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
    OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
    OnInit="Init event handler"
    OnLoad="Load event handler"
    OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
    OnUnload="Unload event handler"
    runat="server"
    SkinID="string"
    Style="string"
    TabIndex="integer"
    Target="string|_blank|_parent|_search|_self|_top"
    Text="string"
    ToolTip="string"
    Visible="True|False"
    Width="size"
/>
```

More info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

Comment: He never suggests that he's using ASP.NET

Comment: I guess I assumed when he had `<button ...` in the question `:(`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just set the background on a button so it looks like a link:

```
.no-bg{background: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it HAS to be a button you can use CSS to make it look and act like a link. ie, hiding the background, making it change color on hover. but best bet is to make it into an actual link w/ an href property.